# Best way to do asp.net mvc5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I got a question I want to make a project to learn asp.net mvc. 
I were thinking of having a eCommerce site, so I came up with this model.

```
    class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }
}
```

But when I add an item I also want the option to have a drop down for diffrent items like Clothes, car etc. What would the best way to do this be?

I guess I could just do an enum like this:

```
public enum ProducType
{
    Car,
    Clothes
}
```

The only downside I see with a enum is I have to hard code the values, what if I want to add another value another day than I would need to change the code.

I guess I Could make a new model called ProductType that just takes an ID and a String called Type and make a relationship. Like this:

```
    class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductType Product { get; set; }
}

class ProductType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; } 
}
```

**What would the best way to take here?**

Comment: Consider making your title more specific. The titular question is *ridiculously* broad.

Comment: Is a red product different from a blue product? Is a light version different from the regular version? Is a product available if a variation thereof is sold out? How? Start with something simpler, like a blog with categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better create Product and Category model class and add a relationship to them. If in a near future you'll add a new category, you won't need a new deploy.

Comment: So having two models would be the 'best' thing to do in my position?

Comment: ASPNET MVC 5 support enum for a dropdown, but as I said, if you want to add a new category, you won't need to recompile your app.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an enum you could also use a list and later just use list.Add method

Answer (score 1):

Your second solution is fine here,

```
class Type
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; } 
}
```

As you said you can have a **Product** class and a **Type** class having a relationship between them.Since if you need to change your dropdown values then you can just update them in database and you would have no need to change your code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you'll add/update/remove categories a lot, so the best option is the two model class and store your categories in the database. In this way, you can change easily data without change the code.

Answer (score 0):

"*I got a question I want to make a project **to learn asp.net mvc**. I were thinking of having a eCommerce site, so I came up with this model.*"

I find it interesting you try to learn ASP.NET MVC5 already imposing a goal so complex, for example, an e-commerce.

However, my tip is;

- First learn the concepts;
- So learn how to use them in a simple way;
- Then try to do complex things;

Here is a great official tutorial to get started:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started